# I get this undefined reference error when I try to install this Perl module

Tags: perl, mingw-w64, msys2

I am using msys2 for mingw and am trying to download this Params::Validate module.  I get this error, but can't find online what the problem is.  I would really appreciate it if you could tell me what's wrong and how to fix it.
Thanks!

```
cpan[1]> install Params::Validate  
lib/Params/Validate/XS.o:XS.c:(.text+0x34c): undefined reference to  'Perl_hv_common_key_len'
lib/Params/Validate/XS.o:XS.c:(.text+0x34c): relocation truncated to fit: 
R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol 'Perl_hv_common_key_len'  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
error building blib/arch/auto/Params/Validate/XS/XS.dll from  
lib/Params/Validate/XS.o at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/CBuilder/Base.pm line 320.
  DROLSKY/Params-Validate-1.19.tar.gz  
  ./Build -- NOT OK  
Failed during this command:  
 DROLSKY/Params-Validate-1.19.tar.gz          : make NO
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a very old installation of perl. The `Perl_hv_common_key_len` was added in Perl v5.8.9 which is nearly seven years ago, so you are running an even earlier release of v5.8. Much of the world is now running v5.22 so I suggest that you update

Comment: "Much of the world is now running v5.22". That's incredibly far from the truth.

Comment: @ikegami: I think you'd better look in your dictionary

Comment: Much of the word is running what their distro packaged 5 years ago.

Comment: @ikegami: Much of the world doesn't have a computer at all

Comment: When I type "perl --version", it says I have 5.22.  Could there be a different problem? (I am very inexperienced with this type of thing.  Sorry if I sound dumb.)